# Comparing two word if they are alike or not, Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, tkinter, text-files

I using Tkinter in Python and I have a optionmenu which contains a set of elements:

**Customer

Workshop

SupplyChain**

Then I have a textfile called *"RestRout3.txt"* which contains a long list:

```
Supplychain/dealer/etc.
Supplychain/parts/etc.
Supplychain/shop/etc.
Supplychain/order/etc.
Supplychain/tasks/etc.
Supplychain/payment/etc.
Workshop/location/etc.
Workshop/name/etc.
Workshop/report/etc.
Customer/info/etc.
Customer/order/etc.
```

In my application I have button, when clicked it will run this method `def Action():`
By doing some if-statements, I want to get both of the same word to be matching.

```
def Action():
    appName = variabel.get() #Element selected from Optionmenu
  
    with open("RestRout3.txt", "r") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        print (content) # reads all the content in file
    return content
    if appName == content[0]: # for example appname(supplychain) and content(supplychain)
        print ("Both words are matching")
```

I expect the both words to be matching, so I can do more function later.

I appreciate all help I can get, thanks.
I'm new to Python.

Comment: "I expect the both words" words is pretty generic. It would help if you actually explained what words you are trying to find and what you are trying to find them in. Currently your question is way to vague for me to answer. The best way to fix that would be first to make sure to explain everything, and second, provide an example input and output.

Comment: For instance Im trying to find "Supplychain" in RestRout3.txt. Then I want to compare the word with one of the items in Optionmenu. If they are matching, I will print out: "Both words are matching".

Comment: "Supplychain" is one word not two. You explicitly say "I expect the both words to be matching". Please go through your question and make sure you are explaining everything properly.

Comment: The code `if appName == content[0]:` will never be executed because of the `return content` statement before it.  Also if `appName` is `"supplychain"`, but `content[0]` is `"Supplychain/dealer/etc"`, so the if condition will always be `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not fully understand the question but in your code i see code after a `return` statement and nothing will be executed after a `return` statement within the function. So move the `return` statement to the end.